# Trying to understand gradle project properties

Tags: gradle

Clearly I don't understand what's going on here.

I guess prop2 and prop3 can't be accessed because they are variables instead of "project properties".

The question arose because I would like the variables prop2 and prop3 to be visible from within the "doTheThing()" method, but I don't want to have to pass them in.  I want the variables to be globally accessible to tasks, methods and classes (but only from within in the build script itself) - and I want them to be typed (which is why the defintion of prop1 is not acceptable).

Really, though - I guess what I'm asking for is some help understanding what a Gradle project property is and what the syntax 'prop1 = "blah"' is actually doing.

I have read the Gradle user guide and also Gradle in Action - if they already explain this concept please point me to the right section (maybe I glossed over it at the time not understanding what is was saying).

```
prop1 = "blah"
String prop2 = "bleah"
def prop3 = "blargh"

task testPropAccess << {
  println "1: $prop1"
  println "2: $prop2"
  println "3: $prop3"
  doTheThing()
}

private void doTheThing(){
  println "4: $prop1"
  println "5: $prop2"  // error: Could not find property 'prop2' on root project 'script'
  println "6: $prop3"  // error: Could not find property 'prop3' on root project 'script'
}
```

Comment: This should also help: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22

Comment: @Rodion - that link was quite useful, thanks.  Guess I need to do some more Groovy-oriented research.

Comment: For anyone looking to do similar, my current workaround for getting the functionality I want is to define my build-script wide properties in a class like this:

`class StaticProps {
  static String prop4 = System.getProperty("prop4", "wibble")
}`

And then use them like this:

`System.getProperty("prop4", StaticProps.prop4)`

Comment: Why `System.getProperty()` twice?

Comment: @Peter - Copy-paste error; should be `println $BuildProps.prop4`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you declare a variable at the outermost level (as in your second and third statement), it becomes a local variable of the script's `run` method. This is really just Groovy behavior, and nothing that Gradle can easily change.

If you want the equivalent of a global variable, just assign a value to an unbound variable (as in your first statement). This adds a dynamic property to Gradle's `Project` object, which is visible throughout the build script (unless shadowed). In other words, `prop1 = "blah"` is equivalent to `project.prop1 = "blah"`.

If you want the equivalent of a typed global variable, you'll have to wait until Gradle upgrades to Groovy 1.8, which makes this possible with the `@Field` annotation. Or you write a plugin that mixes a convention object into the `Project` object (but that's not suitable for ad-hoc scripting).

Comment: For anyone that stumbles across this, it's now recommended that when doing what Peter suggests you instead write `ext.prop1 = "blah"`. The older technique still works but is deprecated and generates a warning. Using ext is just a nice way of explicitly stating that you intend to create a new property. If you think you're using an existing property and are unwittingly making a new one it can be terribly frustrating, so this is probably a pretty good change.

Comment: Hi again Peter. Quick question, I created a `ext.blah = 'foobar'` variable at the top level build.gradle file but it isn't in scope for `buildscript`, any idea why?

Comment: That should be a separate question (if it doesn't exist already).

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I'll create one :)

Comment: @Bob link to this question? I'm curious on this issue also!